# Difference between CATransform3DMakeRotation and CATransform3DRotate

Tags: ios, swift

I was looking at the official documentation of [CATransform3DMakeRotation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/1436558-catransform3dmakerotation) and [CATransform3DRotate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/1436524-catransform3drotate) and I cannot understand what's their difference. Where does someone use `CATransform3DMakeRotation` and where `CATransform3DRotate`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can represent a wide variety of 3D transformations using a 4 x 4 matrix, including translation, scaling, rotation, skewing, and perspective.

You can represent multiple successive transformations in a single matrix by multiplying together the matrices representing each individual transformation.

`CATransform3DMakeRotation` creates a matrix that represents a single transformation: rotation by a given angle around a given axis.

`CATransform3DRotate` creates a matrix just like `CATransform3DMakeRotation` does, and then multiplies that matrix by another matrix, thus adding the rotation to an existing sequence of transformations.

So you really only need one or the other. If you have one, you can easily define the other.

You can write `CATransform3DRotate` using `CATransform3DMakeRotation` like this:

```
func CATransform3DRotate(_ t: CATransform3D, _ angle: CGFloat, _ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ z: CGFloat) -> CATransform3D {
    let rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, x, y, z)
    return CATransform3DConcat(rotation, t)
}
```

`CATransform3DConcat` returns the product of the two matrices.

Or you can write `CATransform3DMakeRotation` using `CATransform3DRotate` like this:

```
func myCATransform3DMakeRotation(_ angle: CGFloat, _ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ z: CGFloat) -> CATransform3D {
    return CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, angle, x, y, z)
}
```

`CATransform3DIdentity` is the identity matrix, and represents no transformation at all.

If you want to understand more about transformation matrices, how to construct and combine them, and why you need a 4x4 matrix for 3D transformations, type [`homogeneous coordinates 3d`](https://www.google.com/search?q=homogeneous+coordinates+3d) into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2):

`CATransform3DMakeRotation` creates a new transform.

`CATransform3DRotate` takes an existing transform and rotates it.

If you're just trying to rotate, there isn't a different really. But if you need to scale, then rotate, then translate, there could be a difference by the end.